# Average # of tracks that must be heard on a CD, whose player's shuffle function can play the same song >1×, before all tracks of CD heard.

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a CD of $n$ tracks. Your CD player's shuffle function is broken; it selects a random song, possibly even the one(s) already played, before all tracks are played. How many tracks (possibly duplicates), on average, does one need to listen to to hear every song at least once?

The solution to this problem is $n H(n)$ where $H(n)$ is the n$^\mathrm{th}$ harmonic number.

How is this derived?

Comment: This is essentially the same as the coupon collector's problem

Comment: @MarkBennet: I've never heard of that problem. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: *essentially*? this IS the [coupon collector's problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coupon+collector%27s+problem).  Or maybe CD track collector's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).